# gitでmergeしても差分が反映されない

Tags: git, github

gitでtanakaブランチの変更をsatouブランチに取り込みたいですが、mergeしても差分が反映されません。
考えられる解決策を教えていただけますと幸いです。

```
$ git checkout satou
$ git merge tanaka
Already up to date.
```

ちなみにsatouブランチをpullする際に、以下のコマンドを使用しました。

```
$ git fetch origin satou
$ git reset --hard origin/satou
```

また`$git branch -a -v`の結果は以下になります。

```
$ git branch -a -v
  tanaka                679a376 田中(私)の編集分
  main                    9832e3d 11/8 終了分
* satou                   bc1ee17 佐藤の編集
  remotes/origin/tanaka 679a376 田中(私)の編集分
  remotes/origin/main     9832e3d 11/8 終了分
  remotes/origin/satou    bc1ee17 佐藤の編集
```

Comment: この手の質問は第三者が質問者が欲しい正解と現状を把握するために問答を繰り返すより、質問者がGUIツールで解決した方が早いと思います。具体的に分からないことがあったときだけ聞くようにしましょう。どうしてもcommandでやりたいならgit log --graph --statとかで少し分かると思います。

Comment: `git diff satou tanaka` を実行してコードの差分は表示されますか？

Comment: git diff satou tanakaで差分（tanakaブランチから取り込みたかったコード）が表示されていましたが、作業を行っているうちにいつの間にか差分がなくなり、取り込みたかったコードも取り込めていました。一応解決はしましたが原因は分からぬままです。githubの基本から学び直した方が良さそうです。お騒がせしました。

Comment: GUIツールというアイディアについても感謝します。